# How to recalculate variable?

Tags: java

I'm thinking of making a variable calculate every time I call/use them? Is that even possible?

```
int myvalue = rn.nextInt(100 - 1 + 1) + 1;
System.out.println("call myvalue: " + myvalue);
System.out.println("call myvalue again: " + myvalue);
System.out.println("call myvalue the third time: " + myvalue);
```

Comment: simple as it is: Make a method, not a variable.

Comment: I guess it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to call a java method using a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138527/how-to-call-a-java-method-using-a-variable-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, create a method:

```java
static int myvalue(Random rn) {
    return rn.nextInt(100 - 1 + 1) + 1;
}
```

```java
System.out.println("call myvalue: " + myvalue(rn));
System.out.println("call myvalue again: " + myvalue(rn));
System.out.println("call myvalue the third time: " + myvalue(rn));
```

Option 2, use a lambda expression *(Java 8+)*:

```java
IntSupplier myvalue = () -> rn.nextInt(100 - 1 + 1) + 1;
System.out.println("call myvalue: " + myvalue.getAsInt());
System.out.println("call myvalue again: " + myvalue.getAsInt());
System.out.println("call myvalue the third time: " + myvalue.getAsInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method which will return `int` like this:

```java
static int myvalue()
{ 
    Random rn= new Random();  
    return rn.nextInt(100 - 1 + 1) + 1;
}
```

and call it in `System.out.println()`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{                       
  System.out.println("call myvalue: " + myvalue());
  System.out.println("call myvalue again: " + myvalue()); 
  System.out.println("call myvalue the third time: " + myvalue());
}
```